# ReactJS memory/storage leak in chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I have a site that I built for a client using ReactJS. You can view the site here:

http://www.designcollaborate.com/

It appears that after some time with the app open, the system storage begins to fill up. Kind of like a memory leak.

On Mac, I can watch my available space slowly diminish the longer I keep chrome open. Eventually, the app crashes and shows this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I can't seem to find how I can see when chrome saves files to disk and where. Anything that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you remove listeners or any kind of subscriptions in `componentWillUnmount` to avoid memorly leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I got by debugging the site.

The detached objects.

[image]

The whole overview. 
[image]

From my side, there are tons of detached objects that lead to memory leak indeed. And, the number of living dom nodes keeps increasing as well.  These things might be the major reason that makes the site be bigger and slower.

Comment: This is fantastic! I come from a more embedded background and it didn't make sense to me that a memory leak would eat up storage space. Am I understanding it correctly that this is what is happening? If so, I can definitely use these tools to troubleshoot

Comment: @DerekNowicki Yes, you are correct. It's better to fix the memory leak before the next step. Btw, I also found the js execute time too long to respond to user actions. That might be the next step in improving the performance of the site. Docs may help you move forward. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems, https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the links. I'm going to check those out. The delay on user actions is deliberate per the client. During the slide show, links aren't clickable until the animated transition effect is done playing. Lots of moving parts on that home page. Looking at my code, there are a ton of event listeners that I'm not cleaning up, which is a pretty easy fix with the `componentWillUnmount` method. With those links I think I have all that I need to get this stuff sorted out. Much appreciated!

Comment: @DerekNowicki You are welcome. I know you’ll do the same for someone else.